# Tile with a lot of images from terminal

Tags: terminal, images

Suppose I have a directory with 30 images. Is that possible to create a big image using these images as tiles?

Suppose all images have the same size, like 120x80 and I want to create a big image with 6 rows x 5 columns of these images with no space between them?

Is that possible to do that from terminal using, for example, SIPS or another app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php);

```
montage *.jpg -mode Concatenate -tile 6x5 montage.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for useful answer. If you want to tile say just one row you can use `-tile x1` or for 2 columns `-tile 2x`